# Mysql JOIN and WHERE issue

Tags: mysql

Can someone help me out with this query??

```
SELECT  a.filename AS thumbpath, b.filename AS imagepath, name 
FROM gallerythumbs AS a WHERE gallery = 1
JOIN galleryimages AS b 
USING(id) ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT   $start, $per_page
```

I have 3 galleries with the data being added to a msqyl table. Each gallery gets either 1, 2,or 3 put in the gallery field.

Where do I put this line

```
WHERE gallery = 1
```

Thanks for looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WHERE` goes after `FROM` (after all the `JOIN`s)

```
FROM
    gallerythumbs AS a
    JOIN galleryimages AS b USING (id)
WHERE
    gallery = 1
```

`USING(id)` is probably incorrect in this case.  You may want to use something like `ON (a.id = b.galleryid)` instead.